# Set Color Select entire row of a DataGrid, and MouseOver Behaviour after Changing Background Color

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mouseover, selecteditem

My question is about a DataGrid inside a Page Form, programming with C#.NET 4.0. The application is for desktop, not web or Silverlight.

I've made a change into a DataGrid of our page, than changes background. Unfortunately, when i select a row, it only changes to blue (color which identifies is selected) only affect the columns of that row. Inside some of these datagrids, i have some space left. What I need to do, is to select that row entirely, including that blank space.

Another thing which have changed, is a Mouse Behaviour when Mouse is over any record. After this change, now this behaviour doesn't happen anymore.

Any clue what I need to do?

**Edit:** Adding code:

My Converter:

```
public class RetornaCorFundoGrid : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static DependencyProperty CorFundoGridParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CorFundoGridParameter", typeof(IEnumerable<Object>), typeof(RetornaCorFundoGrid));

    public IEnumerable<Object> CorFundoGridParameter
    {
        get { return ((IEnumerable<Object>)GetValue(CorFundoGridParameterProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(CorFundoGridParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToInt16(value) < 5)
                return Brushes.BlueViolet;
            if (System.Convert.ToInt16(value) < 15)
                return Brushes.CadetBlue;
            else
                return Brushes.Coral;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Brushes.Black;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My Binding Reflector:

```
<ut:BindingReflector Target="{Binding Mode=OneWayToSource, Source = {StaticResource RetornaCorFundoGrid}, Path=CorFundoGridParameter}" 
                         Source="{Binding Parameters, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

My Row Style:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Id, Converter={StaticResource RetornaCorFundoGrid}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my problem... We use a ResourceDictionary.xaml. And inside of it, we have a behavior definition of DataGridRow. When i define it inside this component, i override it.

So, to resolve this problem, ive added a BasedOn:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Id, Converter={StaticResource RetornaCorFundoGrid}}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle >
```

Simply, but annoying..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding what you're asking for, but maybe this will help.  For making a table that you select by full row only, you can set the SelectionMode to FullRowSelect.  Then any time you click anywhere on the table, you get the full row of the cell you clicked on.

As for coloring the cells, you can iterate through the Columns within the current Row and set both the BackColor and SelectionBackColor to whatever color you want, like so:

```
foreach (DataGridCell cell in myRow.Cells)
{
    cell.Style.BackColor = myColor;
    cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = myColor;
}
```

Not sure what's up with the mouse over behavior.

Comment: No no no... I actually can change my background color. My problem is, when i do that, and select a row, not the entire row changes the colour of selection, because my grid doesn't fill up with columns. As still there space for more 2 or 3 columns, i want to make this selection color fills entirely the row grid, even if there's no more column to fill.
Could clarify my question?

Answer (score 0):

To color the entire row of the DataGrid you'll need to set a style for the `DataGrid.RowStyle` that defines the background color of the row. You may need to set the background of the cells to transparent (so as not to hide the row color) or change them to match the row color. Additionally, you will need to set the selection color and an EventTrigger that handles the mouse over event.

Comment: I've added some code to my question. I've already set a style to rowStyle. I need to fill the line, where it has no data or columns, but the remaining space on the Grid. E voltar o comportamento do Mouse Over. 
Better clarify: we've create a component that inherits from the DataGrid. We define MouseOver inside this component. Therein lies our problem, because it comes automatically this MouseOver effect, only after I've added this color conversion, our MouseOver and Entire Row Color Selection had problems.